# How to use LuaLaTeX at WinEdt?

Tags: errors, luatex, miktex, compiling, winedt

I have a problem " How to use LuaLaTeX at WinEdt ? And my MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\luaexec{
tp=tex.print
tp("\\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]")
tp("\\draw (0,0) to (1,1);")
tp("\\end{tikzpicture}")
}
\end{document}
```

And I compile my file and get error like this :

```
Command Line:   lualatex.exe --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "myluacode.tex"
Startup Folder: D:\30032015
Process has been killed ...
```

And Settings for my LuaLaTeX like this :

[image: lualatex configuration]

And I try use Command Prompt but I still get error : 
[image: cmd]

I don't understand " **How to use LuaLaTeX at WinEdt**?"

Comment: Try to rebuild the lualatex format (miktex-settings, tab format, select lualatex and click on build).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Still error , I use MikTeX 64 bit and WinEdt 9.0/8.0 but I still get Error

Comment: Try to compile on the command line to check if winedt is part of the problem (I doubt it). How did you recreate the format? With miktex settings (admin) or with miktex settings? Did you check with the update manager in user *and* admin mode if everything is up-to-date?

Comment: I use miktex settings(admins) and everything is up-to-date

Comment: Then try again with the normal miktex settings (not the admin version). Your command window looks exactly like the one you can get after the last update of the binaries and a faulty/missing format.

Answer (score 1):

[To get this off the unanswered list]

As Ulrike suggests, this has nothing to do with WinEdt.

All you have to do is to rebuild the LuaLaTeX format both for admin and non-admin users.

This can be done by running MiKTeX Settings (Admin) -> Formats tab -> select lualatex and click on build.